# How to dynamically set the size and border of theTreeView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created a TreeView in asp.net page and also set the height and width of the TreeView.But when number of node increased then it did not fit it the specified border.So, I want to dynamically set the size of the TreeView and also set horizontal scroll bar,vertical scroll bar if it overflows.

Please Guide me get out of this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your Treeview in div and put div and treeview in Asp:Panel as follows and set its attribute ScrollBar = "Auto"

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelID" ScrollBars="Auto">
                                    <div id="DivID" runat="server">
                                        <asp:TreeView>
                                              // your treeview nodes goes here
                                        </asp:TreeView>
                                    </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Setting ScrollBar = "Auto" will set the scrollbar both horizontally and vertically

Comment: @Sorry Usman,It is created scorll bar.but how to set the size of the div.

Comment: you can define your treeview Height attribute now to your require one as  <asp:treeview  Height="200px"> /* 200px is for test you will replace it with your own */